# CouchDB cluster database distribution

Tags: couchdb

We have a CouchDB cluster with 24 nodes, with `q=8` and `n=3`as default cluster settings, and 100 databases already created. If we added 24 more nodes to the cluster and started creating new databases, would they be created in the new nodes or not necessarily? How does CouchDB make the decision of where to put the new databases?

We are running all nodes in 2.3.1

Answer (score 3):

By default CouchDB will assign the shards for databases across all the nodes in the cluster randomly, so your new databases will have shards on both the new nodes and the old ones. It will spread the shards across as many nodes as possible, and guarantee that two replicas of a shard are never co-located on the same node.

If you wanted to have shards hosted **only** on the new nodes (e.g. because the old ones are filling up) you could take advantage of the “placement” feature. There are two steps involved:

1. Walk through the documents in the _nodes database and set a “zone” attribute on each document, e.g. “zone”:”old” for your old nodes and “zone”:”new” for the new ones.
2. Define a `[cluster] placement` config setting that tells the server to place 3 copies of each shard in your new zone:

```
[cluster]
placement = new:3
```

You could also use this feature for other purposes; for example, by splitting your nodes up into zones based on rack location, availability zone, etc. to ensure that replicas have maximum isolation from each other. You can read more about the setting here:

http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.3.1/cluster/databases.html#placing-a-database-on-specific-nodes